# Combination between lists ignoring elements within and list and ignoring ordering of pairs

Tags: python, combinations

I have two lists:

```
list1=['a', 'z', 'd', 'e','b']
list2=['d','e', 'b' ]
```

and I need the combinations (not permutations) of the elements of these two lists. I have tried `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.product`, but I am not getting exactly what I want. For example, `('d','d')` would be wrong. `('a','z')` would also be wrong because `'a'` and `'z'` belong to the same list (`list1`) and neither one of them appears in `list2`. Finally, I do not want both `('d','e')` and `('e','d')` - only one of these pairs, since order does not matter. The ideal output would be:

```
('a','d'), ('a','e'), ('a','b'),
('z','d'), ('z','e'), ('z','b'),
('d','e'), ('d','b'), ('e','b')
```

Edit: generally, `list2` will not always be a subset of `list1`, but I want to handle that case as well. There could also be an overlap of these two lists and not a full subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be not most efficient but you can try following:

```
list1=['a', 'z', 'd', 'e','b']
list2=['d','e', 'b' ]

result = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i != j and (j,i) not in result:
            result.append((i,j))
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('a', 'b'), 
 ('z', 'd'), ('z', 'e'), ('z', 'b'), 
 ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'b'), ('e', 'b')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since order does not matter, you should use `set` or `frozenset` for order-agnostic collections.

One brute-force solution is to utilise `itertools.product`, but use `set` combined with a list comprehension to remove duplicates:

```
from itertools import product

list1=['a', 'z', 'd', 'e','b']
list2=['d','e', 'b' ]

res = [i for i in set(map(frozenset, product(list1, list2))) if len(i) > 1]

print(res)

[frozenset({'b', 'e'}),
 frozenset({'a', 'e'}),
 frozenset({'d', 'z'}),
 frozenset({'b', 'd'}),
 frozenset({'a', 'd'}),
 frozenset({'d', 'e'}),
 frozenset({'b', 'z'}),
 frozenset({'a', 'b'}),
 frozenset({'e', 'z'})]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain, product, combinations
common = set(list1) & set(list2)
sdiff = set(list1) ^ set(list2)
result = [i for i in chain(product(common, sdiff), combinations(common, 2))]
```

Then,

```
>>> print(a)
[('b', 'a'), ('b', 'z'), ('e', 'a'), ('e', 'z'), ('d', 'a'), ('d', 'z'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'd'), ('e', 'd')]
```

Comment: Still getting ('b','d') and ('d','b')

Comment: @SteliosM Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with examples like `('d', 'e')` and `('e', 'd')` by sorting the inner tuples:

```
from itertools import product

xs = ['a', 'z', 'd', 'e', 'b']
ys = ['d', 'e', 'b']

got = set(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in product(xs, ys) if t[0] != t[1])
```

Comment: You've managed to fix my not-working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50571254/1 I missed the sorting part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nonefficient way, but working :

```
print(set([z for x in list1 for z in [tuple(x+y) if ord(x) < ord(y) else tuple(y+x) for y in list2 if x != y]]))
```

{('a', 'e'), ('e', 'z'), ('b', 'z'), ('d', 'e'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('d', 'z'), ('a', 'd')}

I realy prefer @jpp solution !